# centering pictures HTML

Tags: html, css

I try to center pictures in the container. I've set left and right margin to 0 and still something is not working right.

```css
#navbut {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: -7px 0 0 0;
  color: white;
}

.container .box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.box img.Newspaper_pic {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="navbut">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="News-pic" class="Newspaper_pic">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="News-pic" class="Newspaper_pic">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="News-pic" class="Newspaper_pic">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

What I am doing wrong that I cannot center pictures in one line?

Comment: I want to obtain all pictures in one line, next to each other. The are displayed one above another.

Comment: You can use `flex`. I have added a solution below...have a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are set to inline-block, you have to use

```css
text-align:center;
```

. If your images are set to block,

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

will work.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your pictures are centered, but only within the .box divs, you have to center those .box divs in the .container aswell. The .container also needs to be width 100% so it spans over the whole #navbut.

Comment: I updated my code. Everything works just fine if pictures are display in a  block. I struggle with fixing to obtain all of pics in one line. When I use display:inline-block, they are moved to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **flex**. `flex` is very easy to make for these kind of layouts because of these alignment properties.

> [Reference Link ***flex***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container, .box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Newspaper_pic {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="navbut">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="News-pic" class="Newspaper_pic">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="News-pic" class="Newspaper_pic">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="News-pic" class="Newspaper_pic">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put whatever you want inside the `center` tags, e.g:

```
<center>
  <img src="" alt="">
</center>
```

Comment: Please note that the HTML `center` tag is [already obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and should be avoided at all costs.